# Contact Form 7: Reset only certain fields?

Tags: wordpress, field, reset, contact-form-7

I'm using Wordpress (5.2.2) and Contact Form 7. How can I reset only certain fields on submit?

The default action on successful submit is to clear all of the form fields. I located what appears to be the call to reset in public_html/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js and commented out the indicated three lines,

```
        if ( 'mail_sent' == data.status ) {
        //  $form.each( function() {
        //      this.reset();
        //  } );

            wpcf7.toggleSubmit( $form );
        }
```

which appears to now prevent resetting of all of the fields when the user clicks "send". However, I have a couple of pull-down selection fields ( [select id "opt1" "opt2" ... ] ) which I need to reset. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( 'mail_sent' == data.status ) {
                $form.each( function() {
                    $.each( $(this)[0], function() {
                        if (!($(this).hasClass("noResetOnMailSent"))){
                            $(this).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').prop('checked', false).prop('selected', false);
                        }
                    } );
                } );
```

this issue already solved on official site of WordPress. check here

> https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-not-clear-or-autofill-certain-fields-after-submission/

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have added that's my comment on that forum stating that solution doesn't seem to work for me. I don't know ANY js so I'm really just copying & pasting here.

Comment: OK, I take that back, I found a way to make it work. For a given field, let's say a text field, I might have: 
[text* your-name class:noResetOnMailSent] 
but it seems if I change it to: 
[text* your-name id:your-name class:noResetOnMailSent] 
then it works.